# What's wrong with my sql when I using FIND_IN_SET function?

Tags: mysql, find-in-set

In my table called testtb has a column that storing file path,Now I want to find the filed which start in `C:\`.I use the sql,but it always return 0.what's wrong?

```
--example 
select  FIND_IN_SET('C:\\', 'C:\\abc.png' )
-- my sql
 select  FIND_IN_SET('C:\\', filepath) from testtb;
```

Here is my table data:

```
id,    filepath,               srcfilepath
'1', 'C:\20160101\abc.jpg', 'C:\20160101\abc.jpg'
'2', 'D:\20160101\abc.jpg', 'D:\20160101\abc.jpg'
'3', 'E:\TP\20160101\abc.jpg', 'E:\TP\20160101\abc.jpg'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just confused. `find_in_set()` refers to sets of values in MySQL. In MySQL, these are values separated by commas: `'1,2,3'` or `'abc,def,ghi'`.

I think you are looking for the `instr()` or `position()` function:

```
select instr('C:\\abc.png', 'C:\\')
```

Answer (score 1):

`find_in_set` is not proper here, and `like` will do what you expect.

```
mysql> select  'C:\\abc.png' LIKE 'C:\\\\%';
+------------------------------+
| 'C:\\abc.png' LIKE 'C:\\\\%' |
+------------------------------+
|                            1 |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```